# Classification of Compact Surfaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds, surfaces

Is there a ***rigorous*** proof of the classification theorem for compact (connected) two-manifolds that describe all of them up to a homeomorphism? I have seen many books and all of them use way too much hand waving. All the current proofs that I seen rely way too much on drawing pictures. Is there an actual rigorous proof which cleanly defines all the concepts and establishes the classification theorem without any hand-waving nor appealing to pictures?

Comment: Different people have different standards of rigor. I suggest, you include the list of proofs that you saw and did not like. By the way, most proofs will take existence of a triangulation of surfaces for granted, it is unclear if this bothers you.

Comment: You could have a look at Massey. Not entirely sure if its rigorously enough for your taste, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not sure why it matters if I include a list of proofs that I do not like. In the original question it is specified that the proof must be picture-free (or at least, express-able as a picture free proof).

Comment: @Zest Please look at the question, "proofs that I seen rely way too much on drawing pictures", and note that Massey also relies too much on drawing pictures.

Comment: It matters because it would prevent people from giving proofs that you dislike as their answers. What you wrote "In the original question it is specified that the proof must be picture-free (or at least, express-able as a picture free proof)" is insufficient since all these proofs can be rewritten without any pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Take a look at André Gramain's *Topology of Surfaces*. I will find [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ejean/surfclass-n.pdf) a list of textbooks which contain a proof of the classification.

Comment: Would you be able to provide where I can find it in Bredon? I looked at the table to contents and the index but I was unable to find it in Bredon's book.

Comment: My memory tricked me. That textbook talks about the classification of such surfaces, yes, but in some exercises, from section III.9. I will delete that reference from my answer. But I will also add another reference.